# Undetected Android emulator with an integrated API?

Tags: android, python, emulator

**"[Does anyone know an] undetected Android emulator with an integrated API?"**

Following specifications:

1. An undetected Android emulator. Many reputable emulators have known signatures, thus any semi-competent developer is aware that his app is being used on one and therefore enabling them to impose restrictions on the emulated instance. I have read [articles](https://www.virtuesecurity.com/defeating-android-emulator-detection/) on how to bypass these checks, though I'm not sure about which emulators are undetected by standard.
2. The emulator should have an in-built API (preferably Python as the rest of my project is written in Python - not a must though). Via the API I'd need to stream inputs (with a delay of maximum ~2s) to the emulated instance.

From that description one might suggest going the route with a real device in combination with ADB. Unfortunately, that doesn't work due to the fact that I'm intending to run multiple instances at once (and I don't have that many physical phones available). A software based solution - without the need of numerous phones - is my preferred way.

That concludes: Does anyone know a library which fulfills the beforehand mentioned criterias?

Comment: Guess I'll bounty the question tomorrow..

Comment: what do you plan to use this solution for?

Comment: @DeveloperACE Well, emulating an Android instance to test various applications. Though I don't think that my use case would change anything with the requirements.

Comment: are you explicitly trying to test how an app you made handles detecting whether it is in an emulator or not? or is this just to circumvent the check on an app written by someone else?

It seems like the android virtual devices menu within Android Studio allows you to install and run many different virtual devices. Is there a reason this kind of thing wouldn't work for you?

Comment: The undetectability is needed because it's an external application of someone else. From my analysis, they've got various checks in place (besides detecting the emulator's signature) to test for an emulated instance. I'm looking to automate a process within that app and thus I need an undetected emulator with an integrated API (to control certain aspects of the device). I usually work with ADB - though due to the amount of devices needed, it's not usable in this specific project.

Comment: Any ideas? ... bounty is running out!

Comment: What have you looked at as alternatives to ADB so far? Are there any commercial app testing solutions that exist?

Comment: Well, ADB works - so I didn't go the route with a factual connection (due to the reasons mentioned above). As far as simulators are concerned, I tried NOX and BlueStacks. No, I'm not aware of any "commercial app testing solutions".